# Resume Test cases from last test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using testng to write selenium test cases and have a Test class in which there are 19 test cases and i stop running the test after the 5th test, is there any way that i can make it start from the 6th test?

Comment: You could try using test groups.

Comment: yeah but with that the tests to be run would be fixed, i am looking for a way by which it can start from the next test after the last completed test if possible.

Comment: I don't think there is one.  Unless you want to modify the TestNG framework.

Comment: 19 @test in single class or separate class?

Comment: @IshitaShah single class itself

Answer (score 0):

you will need to write build a separate interface (a small interface with start,stop buttons etc.) running on separate threads, on which you have the initialize the testng test suite aka the test case you are running.
rather than stopping the test cases you don't want to run, have a "skip" option so its skips the test case and moves to the next one.